# Add row to query result using select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, insert

Is it possible to extend query results with literals like this?

```
select name from users
union
select name from ('JASON');
```

or

```
select age, name from users
union
select age, name from (25,'Betty');
```

so it returns all the names in the table plus 'JASON', or (25,'Betty').

Answer (score 116):

You use it like this:

```
SELECT  age, name
FROM    users
UNION
SELECT  25 AS age, 'Betty' AS name
```

Use `UNION ALL` to allow duplicates: if there is a 25-years old Betty among your users, the second query will not select her again with mere `UNION`.

Comment: Do I have to union them one by one? Is there a way to add multiple rows at the same time?

Comment: @Alex: In SQL Server and PostgreSQL, you can do `SELECT age, name FROM users UNION SELECT * FROM (VALUES (25, 'Betty'), (26, 'Fatty')) q(age, name)`

Answer (score 20):

In SQL Server, you would say:

```
Select name from users
UNION [ALL]
SELECT 'JASON'
```

In Oracle, you would say

```
Select name from user
UNION [ALL]
Select 'JASON' from DUAL
```

Comment: He specified sql server: "from dual" is oracle only

Comment: shouldnt the brackets around ALL be omitted for SQL Server?

Comment: The brackets around ALL here are indicating it's an optional element.

Answer (score 19):

> is it possible to extend query results with literals like this?

Yes.

```
Select Name
From Customers
UNION ALL
Select 'Jason'
```

- Use `UNION` to add Jason if it isn't already in the result set.
- Use `UNION ALL` to add Jason whether or not he's already in the result set.

Comment: I'm using sql server 2005 and running a simple union like my first example, but I get "Incorrect Syntax". Is it explicitly like my example?

Comment: How would you always return 'Jason' as the first item in the return Union list?