# Prepending a row in the result of a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738640/2110294) to a SO question on how to append a row onto a MySQL result, we can do the following to append the value Jason to the names of Customers:

```
Select NAME
From Customers
UNION ALL
Select 'Jason'
```

So we end up with:

```
NAME
Actual Customer 1
Actual Customer 2
Jason
```

But how could we add Jason to the beginning of the results so what we have:

```
NAME
Jason
Actual Customer 1
Actual Customer 2
```

(Would like to do this without using Order By)

Comment: `Select 'Jason' as Name
UNION ALL Select Name
From Customers`

Comment: "Would like to do this without using Order By" - why?

Comment: @onedaywhen Because I am actually doing this with dates and not names, sorting does not work well in this case and I get an unwanted result.

Comment: Well in that case it would probably have been sensible to use dates in your question. _Wouldn't it?_ If I add 2 apples to 3 apples, what do I get? _Well it definitely is not ORANGES now is it?_

Comment: @RiggsFolly Might have but in my opinion it makes it more complicated and besides the point to say that I want to append a string value to a list of dates.

Comment: And if you use ORDER BY then the result will not guarantee to have `JasonDATE` at the top will it

Comment: @RiggsFolly I guess it is specific to my use case, I simply want to output the result once via the MySQL query. I was only suggesting that I do not want to use Order By to achieve this end result. It's a good point that you have though.

Comment: If you omit `ORDER BY` then the order is not guaranteed. Before accepting an answer, be sure you know **why you are sure** you will get the order you require :)

Comment: @juergend Thanks, that was spot on.

Comment: @onedaywhen How is the order not guaranteed here? In my mind it is saying take {this} result set and then add {that} result set onto it? Is that not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
Select 'Jason' As `Name`
UNION ALL
Select Name
From Customers
```

If you want the second query ordered then use something like

```
Select 'Jason' As `Name`
UNION ALL
(Select `myDate`
From Customers
Order By `myDate`
)
```

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile as it helps me to understand MySQL a bit more :-)

Comment: Your second query can be reduced to `Select 'Jason' As Name
UNION ALL
(Select Name
From Customers order by some_column)`